# How to write in json file with Android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, buttonclick

Hello ! I want to change the values ​​in my json file called "*etatButton.json*" but I do not know how.

```
[
{
    "bouton1":"on",
    "bouton2":"on",
    "bouton3":"on",
    "bouton4":"off",
    "bouton5":"on",
    "bouton6":"on",
    "bouton7":"on",
    "bouton8":"on",
    "bouton9":"off",
    "bouton10":"off"
}
]
```

For example I want to change the value of "*bouton1*" from "*on*" to "*off*" after onClick event like this one :

```
public void writeJson(View view) {
    // Write smth in json file
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can get you started....

```
try {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonobject =  new JSONObject();
    jsonobject.put("k1", "v1");
    jsonobject.put("k2", "v2");
    json.put(jsonobject);
    System.out.println(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OUTPUT:

> [{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}]

If you want to be able to change v1 or v2, just use variables